# Convert string in to Datetimeoffset

Tags: c#, sql

I am having a string which has the data like 6/30/2016 12:00:00 AM and using the below code

```
public string ConvertDateCreated(string dateCreated)
{
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
  return DateTime.ParseExact(dateCreated, "MMddyyyy", provider).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
}
```

I am not sure how to convert them in to DateTimeOffset type using TryParseExact so it can be inserted in to Ms SQL Database

Answer (score 0):

The DateTimeOffset object has a constructor that takes a datetime object, so once you have successfully parsed you can simply:

```
var dto = new DateTimeOffset(dateCreated);
```